# Are more than half of scientists who have ever lived alive today?

Tags: quotes, demographics

[This Washington Post article](http://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/the-new-scientific-revolution-reproducibility-at-last/2015/01/27/ed5f2076-9546-11e4-927a-4fa2638cd1b0_story.html) quotes Brian Nosek as making the claim that:

> Brian Nosek offers up a stunning factoid: More than half of the scientists who have ever lived are alive today.

It then challenges the reader to double-check this claim:

> Though, yeah, someone ought to double-check that.

Are half of scientists who have ever lived alive today?

Comment: It probably depends on who you count as a scientist. Science in it's current form is very different from the science performed a thousand years ago. This question can be answered pretty much any way you like.

Comment: Given that roughly 8% of people who have ever lived is alive today, and science as a "thing" is fairly new, I don't see why it should be a controversial claim.

Comment: right i can see this being close, we probably have millions who could be classified as scientists, while even 2-300 years ago maybe thousands could be called scientists.

Comment: Hope someone finds this useful: http://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes_stru.htm

Comment: @WillihamTotland Can you give a source on that 8%?

Comment: @leekaiinthesky I sure can! http://www.prb.org/Publications/Articles/2002/HowManyPeopleHaveEverLivedonEarth.aspx

Comment: [This seems very close to an answer](http://blogs.nature.com/news/2014/05/global-scientific-output-doubles-every-nine-years.html), but mapping from the number of journal articles to the number of scientists seems messy.

Comment: It is incredibly improbably that exactly half are alive today.  Perhaps the claim is "at least half"?

Comment: @gerrit - the claim is "More than half", as stated in the quote at the top of the question :)